# Bluetooth suddenly turned off and will not restart on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, headphones

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. I was listening on my Bluetooth connected headphones when they suddenly turned off, so I attempted a reboot.

I got these error messages, before the reboot initiated:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout
Bluetooth: hci0 sending initial HCI reset command failed (-110)
usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error
usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error
usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error
usb 1-7: device descriptor read/64, error
```

and finally

```
reboot: Restarting system
```

The Bluetooth toggle will not switch to ON right now in the settings page. What I want to know is:

- Why/how could this happen suddenly?
- What do these error messages mean?
- How can I reconnect my Bluetooth headphones once again?

Comment: Probably defective.

Comment: It suddenly worked again @GabrielaGarcia

Comment: Nice :) but it may fail again soon and for good this time. If external consider replacing it.

Comment: I don't see any reason as to why there would be an external issue :S

Comment: I meant if the Bluetooth device is external (USB), obviously.

Comment: Yea, @GabrielaGarcia it is not. Any idea why I'm getting the usb 1-7 error when it's not external

Comment: It's probably a combo WiFi+Bluetooth miniPCIe card or M.2 and some of those use internal USB bus along with PCIe/others.